# How can I point my Documents folder to my One Drive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, my-documents

I have a new computer and my old one had the Documents folder pointed at my One Drive\Documents folder.

I am trying to point it on my new computer, but when I try I get the following:

[image]

Any idea how to set it when this happens?

Comment: Hi, How do you point the old documents to the new computer specificly?

Comment: @GloriaGu Using the Location tab in the documents folder properties